# How to format JSON response using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm using PHP and trying to get values from a MySQL database using jQuery/AJAX.

My mysql table has four columns: id, tail, cg and cw

My php code looks like this:

```
<?php

$inputvalue = $_POST;
$errors = false;
$result = false;

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', "root", "", "tp");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

foreach ($inputvalues as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($value) && !empty($value)) {
        $inputvalues[$key] = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $value );
    } else {
        $errors[$key] = 'The field '.$key.' is empty';
    }
 }

if( !$errors ) {
    $addresult = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM `air_cg` 
        WHERE `tail` = '" . $inputvalue['tail'] . "' 
        ORDER BY `id` DESC

    ";

     if( $result = $mysqli->query($addresult) ) {
        // collect results
        while($row = $result->fetch_all())
        {
            $returnResult = $row;
        }
    }
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);

exit;
?>
```

The resulting JSON has this format:

```
{"result":[["255","Lapdogie","1","2"],["254","Lapdogie","23","234"],["253","Lapdogie","132","454"]],"errors":false}
```

My javascript code that im using for the ajax function and to parse the resulting JSON looks like this:

```
function getcgdata(aa){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "drawchart.php",
        data: {tailnumber:taildata},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
    })
    .success(function(response) {

        $('input').removeClass('error').next('.errormessage').html('');

        if(!response.errors && response.result) {
            $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
        var chartdata=(value);
        var cgdata =(cg.value);
        console.log(chartdata);
        console.log(cgdata);
       });

        } else {

            // append the error to the form
            $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                // add error classes
                $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
            });

        }
    });
}
```

The console log for chartdata shows this:
    ["256", "Lapdogie", "232", "333"]
    ["239", "Lapdogie", "23", "12"]
    ["238", "Lapdogie", "1232", "1232"]

The console log for cgdata only shows one value many times:
    232
    232
    232

I am not sure if the issue is with my PHP code or with the way im trying to parse the JSON.

Comment: @SumanK.C Would I try that in my javascript like this: json_decode(value) ?

Comment: On the row: `var cgdata =(cg.value);`, where is `cg` defined?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson cg is one of the column names in my database

Comment: But your sending the result as an array, not associative array. Your JavaScript has now clue about your database.

Comment: Change `var cgdata =(cg.value);` to `var cgdata = value[2];`

Comment: Btw. You have many errors in your code. I'm surprised it works at all. Example: you're setting: `$returnResult = $row;` which means that you overwrite that variable on each iteration. You also set `$errors= false;` and then use it as an array.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul That did the trick! How can I make that the answer?

Comment: @Bruno Write an answer below and *accept* it.

Comment: Oh.. `foreach($inputvalues as $key => $value)`... you actually set `$inputvalue = $_POST` in the top (without the s). Your using an undefined variable in a foreach. Is this the actual code or a rewritten example?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It was rewritten, sorry about that typo.

Comment: Ok. Just for the future... post the actual code, otherwise you ask us to debug a rewrite, which isn't what we are you want.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Duly noted. Sorry about that.

Comment: You don't need to call `fetch_all` in a `while` loop. Since it returns all the rows, you just need to call it once.

Answer (score 1):

i dont see that you define cg.value..

you use

```
var cgdata =(cg.value);
```

but cg is where defined?

it should be probably something like chartdata[3] .. ?

Comment: I don't understand. When I use cg.value and use console.log(cg.value) it gives me the value of only one returned row from column "cg" in the database.

Comment: @bruno, that's impossible if your json output looks like the one you posted here.

Comment: you have not defined variable cg in this function, so it is probably derived from somewhere else... and it was set last time to 233, so thats why it shows always one value.. you need to use the function( index, value) { variables, so it is in the value variable and you should access it from there..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Well, it somehow does work, i'm not sure how.

Comment: The reason is probably what @LudovitScholtz suggested.

Comment: @LudovitScholtz Thank you, ill look into that at a later stage :)

Answer (score 0):

Rajdeep Paul's suggestion below worked for me for this particular situation:

Change

```
var cgdata =(cg.value);
```

to

```
var cgdata = value[2];
```

I'm aware that there are many issues with my code as pointed out by Ludovit Scholtz and Magnus Eriksson and I shall refine it at a later stage.

Thank you all!